# Taylor's theorem proof of mid - point Newton's method.

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

[image: This is the picture]

So in line 13 - it suddenly appears the root of the function -- alpha, but I am not sure where it comes from. It is a proof of a new type of Newton's method called mid-point newton's method that can achieve cubic convergence.

Comment: Perhaps from $e_n = x_n - \alpha$, i.e. $x_n = \alpha + e_n$ ?